# Coordinate Axes in Visio

Tags: coordinates, visio, axes

I Visio start of coordinates is the left-lower corner. Is there any way to change it, for example set the left-upper corner as a start of coordinate axes?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830915
Use Ctrl + Click on the ruler bar and drag drown to the 0 position you want. Basically the same as creating a guide line, but while holding down the Ctrl key,

Comment: Thanks for not just posting a link, you actually put the answer here

Answer (score -1):

Nope. It's the same coordinate system high school math geometry teaches you in the US. At least, they taught it to me that way...

I do not know of a way you can change it within Visio.

Comment: I already wrote a workaround with ordinate turn over while waiting for the answer.